# Use asure CLI on a raspberry pi

Tags: azure, docker, raspberry-pi

I'm working with some containers and services over AZURE, and want to pull some of the images to a raspberry pi but I'm not finding a way to use the CLI on the raspberry, all the instruction are to install it on X_86 systems, I even try the docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-cli

But getting this errror:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
failed to resize tty, using default size
```

Which is for a wrong arquitecture.

Comment: Can you provide more details such as the CLI command you want to execute in the container?

Comment: @CharlesXu At the moment I want to pull push images to the azure registry, but would like to have the complete CLI if possible

Comment: The problem is that your raspberry pi, not the docker image. Maybe the [document](https://www.docker.com/blog/happy-pi-day-docker-raspberry-pi/) would help you.